# Excel VBA - Searching a column for a particular value and returning the value from the adjacent cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a total noob at VBA and need all the help I can get so I apologise in advance for the dumb question. I feel its the only way I will learn.

I have a spreadsheet with two columns, I simply want to search column A for a particular value (I know what this value is, so can hardcode the value into the code) and return the value in column B and assign it to a variable.

```
Column A             Column B   
Parameter            Value  
TabDocumentPath      Path 1  
FrameworkPath        Path 2  
FrameworkAllFile     Path 3  
FrameworkFullPath    Path 4  
AssembliesPath       Path 5
```

So for example if you look at the above, I would like to search for AssembliesPath in Column A and assign the value in the adjacent cell (Path 5) to a variable.
I know, its quite simple but I cannot seem to find this when I search the archive here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-vlookup-method-excel) for this

```
VariableName = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup("Parameter", Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```

1. **Parameter = lookup value**
   we want to lookup `"Parameter"`
2. **Parameter = lookup range**
   our lookup and return data is in columns A:B of the worksheet named `Worksheet1`
3. **Parameter = column index** (of lookup range) to return
   we want to return the value of column `2` of the lookup range (this is B)
4. **Parameter = exact match or an approximate match**
   `False` means exact match

Comment: couple of little hints about making this sort of `VLookUp` call a bit shorter in VBA; if the whole function call will be constant you can write the whole statement as `var  =  [VLookup("parameter",Workheet1!A:B,2,False)]`, if just the range is constant, you can swap `Worksheets("Worksheet1").Range("A:B")` with `[Worksheet1!A:B]`

Comment: @TaylorScott the notation with `[ ]` is just a shortcut to the `Evaluate()` function. But calling the WorksheetFunctions directly is usually faster than `Evaluate()` and they throw errors you can catch in VBA. So I prefer not to use `Evaluate()` at all.

Comment: Absolutely, but the `[ ]` notation is far shorter and easier to read. There are absolutely cases where using the full `WorksheetFunction` notation is necessary, but the `[ ]` has it's merits for VBA users who need to insure readability with other users who may not have extensive coding experience. It is simply more familiar and thus easier for inexperienced users to accept.

Comment: @TaylorScott Well, yes, this is probably a question of personal preference which one to use (if speed doesn't matter). Since I come from the code section the `[ ]` notation looks very unfamiliar to me and not easier to read ;)

Comment: Thank you so much all. This worked first time perfectly!! Seems so simple when its like out like that.

Comment: @Geminiflipflop If this solved your question please mark the answer as solution, so other users can see that this was solved.

Comment: Sorry Peh. How exactly do i do that? Do i just mention it in the comments or is there like a button or something that assigns the answer as the solution??